# The CurrentDirectory property does not show up in the RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS

Tags: c++, windows-driver

I'm using a minifilter driver to intercept process creation and am trying to get the information about the Working Folder where the aplication is starting for.

For this, I got the ProcessParameters from the PEB, and the Internet is saying that there should be an undocumented property for CurrentDirectory.

Can this information actually be found there? How should I get it? Is there somewhere else I can find this information?

Comment: https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/ntoskrnl/inc/api/pebteb/rtl_user_process_parameters.htm